# SAS SQL Macro to join multiple datasets into one

Tags: sql, macros, sas

What it the problem with the below SQL Macro?

I have multiple datasets called "C_out1" 2,3,4 and so on and I would like to extract just one number from each dataset into one new table. I have searched and searched for help but without any luck.

I have tested the code without the macro element on just one dataset and that works fine, but when I try to make it dynamic with the below code, it fails.

I'm able to do the job with a simple datastep, but I'm fairly new to the SQL language, and I would really like to be able to do this. There's almost 200.000 datasets I have to join so I'm guessing that SQL is preferable to the data step.

I get the error:

```
"NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "I".
1             C_out5
              ------
              78
ERROR 78-322: Expecting a ','.

974          where label2='c';
975  quit;
```

Code:

```
 %macro loop(prefix2);
    %do i=1 %to 5;
        &prefix2&i
        %let i = %eval(&i+1);
    %end;
    %mend loop;

    PROC SQL;   
    create table CTOTAL as
        select nvalue2
        from %loop(C_out)
        where label2='c';
    quit;
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, i'll note here that you're probably doing whatever you're doing in an inefficient manner, if it requires creating 200,000 datasets.  Are you doing a bootstrap analysis or something like that?

Comment: Creating 200k datasets is not the right way to go about any database related task.  If this is part of your process you should definitely rethink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data step is a significantly better method to do this than SQL.

```
data CTOTAL;
set C_out:;
where label2='c';
run;
```

If you're not using all of the c_out datasets, you might need to do some work to improve this, but if you are using all c_out datasets then this will work as is.

Answer (score 1):

Joe's answer is best.

If you must use SQL:

Your SQL is not correct.  You need to do this with a UNION ALL. This solution will work for SQL:

```
%macro loop(prefix2);
    %do i=1 %to 4;
        select nvalue from &prefix2&i where str='c' union all
    %end;
    select nvalue from &prefix2&i where str='c'
%mend loop;

PROC SQL;   
create table CTOTAL as
    %loop(C_out)
    ;
quit;
```

1. No need to manually increment the `&i` value.
2. The loop will put `&i` to (n+1) at the final loop, so make the loop go to (n-1) and just output the last statement outside the loop.

Comment: Both, thanks a lot for your answers. It was my impression that SQL usually is better than data steps, that's why I wanted to use SQL (and to practice and explore the opportunities). 
The ~200k data sets are the result of ~200k regressions each outputting some C and AIC measures that I wanted to compare. By having all the data in one data set it's easy to sort and find the highest and lowest values. That's why I wanted to use SQL to merge the data. I don't think there's any easy way around that.

Comment: You can test both and see which takes the least amount of time.  The DATA Step COULD be slower because of the overhead of loading the PDV for each record.